# How to pronounce 'engine'?

Tags: pronunciation

What is (or what are) the correct way(s) of pronouncing 'engine'?

In fact, I think I know the answer; I asked native speakers (UK, US, Australia) several times, and they all pronounced the "i" in 'engine' like in 'native'. But people in my country almost always pronounce the 'i' in 'engine' like in 'dynamite' which causes me to doubt myself. So I thought I should ask here to get the final, undisputed, and expert answer.  I need more than a Google answer; I want to know if there's only one pronunciation for "engine" around the world.

Are there major differences in the pronunciation in UK or US (etc.) for this word specifically?

Not to mention the way it is pronounced in countries (such as mine) where English is not the mother tongue. I live in France; the people I mentioned are software engineers like me.

Comment: It's easier to answer questions like this if you do some research first, and then tell us what you know already. That way, people can focus on explaining the things that can't easily be found elsewhere on the web. For example, have you looked at the pronunciations given for this word in [online dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=engine&ls=a) (or even, paper dictionaries that you have access to)? If so, are there any particular things about the dictionary entries that are confusing to you, or that you have more specific questions about?

Comment: Makes sense ! In fact I asked several times natives (UK, US, Australia) and the all pronounced the "i" in 'engine' like in 'native' but almost every one in my country say the 'i' like in 'dynamite' so I regularly come to doubt, so I thought I should ask here.

Comment: Type `define engine` in Google.  Click on the little speaker icon that is displayed.

Comment: /'ɛnʤən/ is the normal pronunciation in the United States. The second syllable, being unstressed, is reduced to a central vowel, and is never diphthongized.

Comment: What "people"? What "country"?

Comment: @Clare I live in France ; the people I mentioned are software engineers like me.

Comment: @Hot Licks I need more than a Google answer ; I want to know if there's only one pronounciation for "engine" around the world.

Comment: If it's pronounced by more than one human then there's more than one pronunciation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Engine* is pronounced   ​ /ˈen.dʒɪn/ (unstressed second syllable)  in both American English and British English. Check most online dictionaries, including [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/engine?a=british).

You can also check [Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/Engine/en/), which has 39 pronunciations of the word in English, all pronounced 
 as above.

I've never heard the word pronounced differently by any native speaker of English anywhere.

On the other hand, the word *turbine* is usually pronounced with a "long i".

/ˈtɜː.baɪn/, for example, in BrE.

Although Cambridge says another American English pronunciation is with a reduced second  vowel 
/ˈtɜr·bən/.

Check [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/turbine?q=Turbine)  and [Forvo](https://forvo.com/search/Turbine/en/).

So despite the words ending with the same last three letters, the last syllable is pronounced differently in British English and, in my experience,  by most Americans.  Be sure to check the [sentence on Forvo](https://forvo.com/phrase/a_turbine_is_an_engine_where_a_rotor_with_blades_is_caused_to_spin_by_pressure) that has both words in it. The speaker, a male from Canada, pronounces them both as outlined here, ie, differently.